# How to call context.getExternalFilesDir in Qt

Tags: java, android, c++, qt

I am using Qt `5.13.0` and the `androidextras` library. Using the `QAndroidJniObject` I am trying to call the Java method `context.getExternalFilesDir(null)`, in order to obtain the `/storage/emulated/0/Android/data` path. The `QStandardPaths` doesn't cover this path so I think I am forced to do this this way. All native Android applications have their directories in the `/storage/emulated/0/Android/data` with the following nomenclature: `com.company.appname`. I am trying to accomplish the same in Qt. In my manifest XML file I have set the correct package name.

I don't know how to use the `QAndroidJniObject` in c++ code in order to get the path.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[QAndroidJniObject Class](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qandroidjniobject.html) has some info about how to use the jni, but in general it takes some practice to understand how it works.

This should give you the result you need. I put it inside `main.cpp`, but place it where you need it, and make sure to add `#include <QtAndroidExtras>` in your .h or .cpp file:

```
auto androidContext = QtAndroid::androidContext();

QAndroidJniObject dir = QAndroidJniObject::fromString(QString(""));

QAndroidJniObject path = androidContext.callObjectMethod("getExternalFilesDir",
                                                         "(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/io/File;",
                                                         dir.object());

qInfo() << "Path: " + path.toString();
```

Output: `"Path: /storage/emulated/0/Android/data/org.qtproject.example.untitled/files"`

Comment: Does.. Exactly... What you have said it would.